# SVM in R package e1071

Tags: r, svm

I am trying to use SVM to make a prediction (True or False) on a dataset with many independent variables.  I am wondering how I can identify the most useful variable in making the prediction.  I understand that there is a function that allows me to calculate the "weights" of the variables in R package `e1071`.

```
w=t(model$coefs)%*% model$SV
```

But I am not sure how I can decide which are the important variables, based on these weights.

Comment: How about you just try to do PCA first and SVM later.

Answer (score 1):

The `caret` package has useful utilities for variable selection. The `rfe` function performs recursive feature selection. Reference this answer for a demo: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17530483/819544